# Lua Retrieving Multiple Files

Tags: file, lua

I'm trying to achieve a way to retrieve and read multiple .txt files and most likely save into a table. The issue is I can't figure out what API I should be using. Can anyone help me out?
My sorry of excuse code, I don't know the properties of file objects so there is that...

```
local TxtArchive = "\TxtArchive";
for i,v in pairs(io.open:read(TxtArchive)) do
    print(v)
end

io.read()
```

Comment: You can traverse lines of a text file `for line in io.lines(filename) do ... end` or just read whole file as one huge string `local text = io.open(filename):read("*a")`

Comment: But that would require complex string patterns to separate each section...

Comment: The main issue here is getting a correct path to get to the file that needs to be read...

Comment: What sections are you talking about?  You did not mention it in your question.  Give an example.